# How to query message tracking details in maximo

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I wanted to query the message tracking details like xml, error message, ect from maximo. I am not aware how to do that, Does anyone have any idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can query the MAXINTERRORMSG table.

Other related tables:

 - MAXINTERROR

 - MAXINTMSGTRK

 - MAXINTMSGTRKDTL

Comment: Yes, but if we want to view the xml message from database. I dont know how to do that. Any idea?